# If $L$ is a linear mapping then $L(0) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Suppose $L: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear mapping, then $L(\overrightarrow{0}) = \overrightarrow{0}$

What is the proof of this? Why must this be true anyway?

Comment: $L(0) = L(0 + 0) = L(0) + L(0)$.

Comment: $L(0_m) = L(00_m)=0L(0_m)=0_m$

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because

$$
L(v) = L(v+0) = L(v) + L(0)
$$

Substracting $L(v)$ to each side completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

- $L(\mathbf{0}) = L(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{0})=L(\mathbf{0})+L(\mathbf{0})$, so cancelling $L(\mathbf{0})$ on both sides gives the desired result.
- $L(\mathbf{0}) = L(0\cdot \mathbf{0}) = 0\cdot L(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, if + is an operation on the field then
$$L(a + \vec{0}) = L(a) + L(\vec{0}) = L(a)$$
By linearity. Thus, only $\vec{0}$ has this property for all $a$, so it must be that the linear operators sends the zero vector from one domain to its associated zero vector in the codomain.